# What is the difference between creating an object on stack and creating an object on heap?

Tags: oop

Also, Can you define a class such that you can make its objects on heap but not on stack?

Comment: which programming language you want to use?

Comment: I want to use JAVA, is the second part possible in both c++ and java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that only Primitive types exist on the stack, while complex types (objects) are created on the heap, and referred to by primitive pointers on the stack. Also, stack values are removed as soon as they go out of scope, while objects allocated on the heap persist beyond their original scope, and are ultimately garbage-collected.

To my way of thinking, objects are not created on the stack at all, ever. Pointers to objects allocated on the heap are created on the stack. So unless I am missing something critical (always a possibility!) the answer to your second question is that your class, and all of its internal objects, will be created on the heap no matter what you do. All that exists on the stack is a reference pointer to the object location on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

■ Instance variables and objects live on the heap.

■ Local variables live on the stack.